# How to upload/insert image/photo on mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I searched for some solution and it seems can work by adding some code in it. My codes seems doesn't work. I don't know what to do. I'm new in php. The input type file seems working but the upload button doesn't work and it seems that is the problem of this.

```
<?php
include ('LoginFunction.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','danganan');
$user = $_SESSION['Username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblactivity WHERE Username = '$user'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

**This is the upload function**

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
                    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                    $file_tem_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                    $file_store = "uploads/".$file_name;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tem_loc, $file_store)) {
                        echo "Image uploaded!";
                    }
                }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Profile info</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="container">
            <h1><?php echo "Welcome " . " " . $user; ?></h1>
            <img src="<?php $row['Picture']; ?>" width=150; height=150;>
            <div class="send-button">
                <input type="file" name="file" style="margin-right: -76px;"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
                <?php
                $folder = "uploads/";

                if(is_dir($folder)) {
                    if ($open = opendir($folder)) {
                        while (($file = readdir($open)) !=false) {
                            if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
                            echo '<img src ="uploads/'.$file.'" width = "150" height=150>';
                        }
                        closedir($open);
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="usrid" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
            <h2>FIRST NAME</h2><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row['Fname']; ?>">
            <h2>LAST NAME</h2><input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row['Lname']; ?>">
            <h2>USERNAME</h2><input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo $row['Username']; ?>">
            <h2>PASSWORD</h2><h3><?php echo $row['Password']; ?></h3>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be you need to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in tag form

Comment: @AkkapongKajornwongwattana It works LOL! Thank you very much. Laughing at myself right now xD